# Bluescreen in Windows

Tags: windows-7, memory-error

Last time I start Windows there was an error and then a blue screen appeared.
It said "STOP: 0x0000003b" and it forced me to shutdown my PC. It said that something might be wrong with some software or hardware.

Answer (score 1):

This error has been associated with Firewire issues in Windows 7.  Can you specify Windows version?

MS has a [Hotfix](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/980932) for the FireWire issue

Have you updated any drivers recently?

Have you booted and tried Last Known Good?  That may help.

Comment: i use windows 7 ultimate...
i don't know... as i remember i install some software, but i can't remember what the software...

Comment: Does Last Known Good work?  Do you have a firewire device?

Comment: no, i don't have any firewire device.

Comment: Last known good?

Answer (score 0):

Does it happen often? Is this the first time it happened? What were you doing before it happened?

You should be able to find a mini (kernel memory) dump file in C:\Windows\Minidump.

You can use NirSoft BlueScreenView to view the dump files and to try to pinpoint the cause of the problem.

You can download it here:

http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/blue_screen_view.html

Comment: i alredy tried this software.. but nothing happened...
and some app become unavailable in my windows..

Comment: @AndikaSetiawan So you have installed BlueScreenView? What happens when you start it? Do you have any files stored at C:\Windows\Minidump? And again, does it happen often or is this the first time it happened? And also again, what were you doing before this happened?

Comment: it doesn't show anything...
and it happen often.. i install some software. but i can't remember the name of software..

Comment: @AndikaSetiawan You need to go to C:\Windows\Minidump and tell us if you have any files in there? If there are no files in this folder then this is why BlueScreenView can not show you any debugging information, because it has no dump files to read from. By default it scans for dump files in that folder, but you can make it look for dump files in other folders as well. Other reasons for not having the dump files stored there could be because the dump feature is disabled in Windows. More on that later, start by telling us if you have any files in that folder or not.

Comment: i dont have any file in that...
so is there a way to fix it??

Comment: @AndikaSetiawan Click Start menu, right-click on Computer, click Properties. Click Advanced System Settings on the left. Under Startup and Recovery click on Settings. In the System failure section, click on the drop-down menu and choose "Kernel memory dump". Uncheck the option "Overwrite any existing file". The next time you see this BSOD take a look into C:\Windows\Minidump again, and do a file search for *.dmp while in C:\Windows. Not the location of the dump files and open BlueScreenView, go to Options, Advanced Options and make sure you see the same folder path in there. If not, change it.

Comment: @AndikaSetiawan Take a look at this guide on how to use BlueScreenView: http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/6292/how-to-troubleshoot-the-blue-screen-of-death/